# Do you twist your pillow when you sleep

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

Some people have the habit of moving their pillow and also twisting it (it makes them feel more comfortable). So is it natural to use "twist" in this context? If not, what are the more common alternatives?

> Do you **twist** your pillow when you sleep?

Is the use of "twist" natural?

P.S. It's just twisted randomly and not along a plane. It becomes a little spiral shapedand not a square (like when it's folded. It's two ends don't overlap each other.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [**"to fold"**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fold) fits better the situation you describe.

> **fold** (verb) = to bend something, especially paper or cloth, so that one part of it lies on the other part, or to be able to be bent in this way:
>
> - I **folded** the letter (in half) and put it in an envelope.
> - He had a neatly **folded** handkerchief in his jacket pocket.
> - Will you help me to **fold** (up) the sheets?
> - The table **folds** up when not in use.

---

However, since you mention a spiral-like shape, then it is "**twisting**". I am not aware of anybody doing this, I cannot imagine why one would undergo the effort, but "**twist**" seems to be the right word for that particular action.

Comment: No it's just random twisting and not folding it along a plane.

Comment: Another way to see the words (I also want to understand better what you look for): Twist = like you want to squeeze the water out of some cloth (obtaining a spiral-like shape). Fold = when you put a part of it over itself to make it thicker (it is not about making it look nice or choosing a certain line along which to bend, it is about changing the shape of the pillow).

Comment: I did not notice the edit of the question previously. If it is a spiral-like shape, then it is twisting. I am not aware of anybody doing this, I cannot imagine why one would undergo the effort, but "twist" seems to be the right word.

Answer (score 0):

Twist can be used here, but usually narrower things are twisted. **Squeezed** can be used here too.

Answer (score 0):

[Contort](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/contort) would also work in this context:

> Twist or bend out of the normal shape

[This definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/contort) includes the term *violently*, but I don't think in practice that's necessarily a requirement (even some of their examples don't occur in violent contexts).

> to (cause something to) twist or bend violently and unnaturally into a different shape or form:

Comment: Contortionists, as an example, contort their bodies, though I've not seen one do it violently before. Unnaturally, definitely.